# Python multiprocessing Pool, OSError: Errno 2 No such file or directory

Tags: python, mapping, pool

I'm trying to use this [github](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/AudioNotebooks) repo to do some birdsong analysis. I've come across a problem in the stage where I collect all the sample's into one array(['Collect Samples'](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/AudioNotebooks/blob/master/Collect%20Samples.ipynb)). I'm getting an error that looks to be something to do with my system. Not sure where to start on fixing the error. (have a look at my link to the [github](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/AudioNotebooks) repo to get more in depth.) Thanks for having a look!

```
def job(fn):
    return load_sample(fn, sr=sr,
                       max_length=max_length, fixed_length=fixed_length)
pool = Pool()
%time results = pool.map(job, files[:limit])
print 'Processed', len(results), 'samples'


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5d12f8de2a12> in <module>()
      3                        max_length=max_length, fixed_length=fixed_length)
      4 pool = Pool()
----> 5 get_ipython().magic(u'time results = pool.map(job, files[:limit])')
      6 print 'Processed', len(results), 'samples'

/home/notebook/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2156         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2157         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2158         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2159 
   2160     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/notebook/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2077                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2078             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2079                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2080             return result
   2081 

<decorator-gen-59> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/home/notebook/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/home/notebook/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.pyc in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1183         else:
   1184             st = clock2()
-> 1185             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1186             end = clock2()
   1187             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

/home/notebook/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    249         '''
    250         assert self._state == RUN
--> 251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    252 
    253     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

/home/notebook/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    565             return self._value
    566         else:
--> 567             raise self._value
    568 
    569     def _set(self, i, obj):

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Also in case it helps, I'm running Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0.

Oh and the line that causes the error is `results = pool.map(job, files[:limit])`

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu/issues/36 Could be this problem as I've been having real issues installing ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following my comment i posted I tried installing ffmpeg using

`sudo apt-get install libav-tools`

from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426543/install-ffmpeg-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts).
Not sure how that installs ffmpeg but it fixed the problem!

If I should delete this post please tell me, but I think it is useful for other people with a similar problem. ie. no need to learn about mappers and pools if you have a similar problem.